# Pandas: Cannot query

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to query my data-frame object, the following happens:

```
df2.query('a==1')

.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/align.pyc in _align_core(terms)
     96                 reindexer_size = len(reindexer)
     97 
---> 98                 ordm = np.log10(abs(reindexer_size - term_axis_size))
     99                 if ordm >= 1 and reindexer_size >= 10000:
    100                     warnings.warn('Alignment difference on axis {0} is larger '

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log10
```

Here's how my data-frame looks:

```
In [16]: df2.head()
Out[16]: 
                     S         t        S         t    S-elas     t-elas
y                  0.9       0.9      1.0       1.0                     
T a   k   c                                                             
1 0.1 0.2 0.4      NaN       NaN  49.9547  0.935831       NaN        NaN
          0.5  48.4641   0.91747  51.6021  0.893594 -0.595826   0.250475
      0.3 0.4  43.3879  0.930355  44.7448  0.935127 -0.292537 -0.0486025
          0.5  43.1652  0.915278  45.5227  0.888028 -0.505053   0.287115
  1.0 0.2 0.4  7.82282  0.922999  7.95204   0.93587 -0.155631  -0.131551
```

What's going on? It doesn't work no matter whether I choose 'T==1', 'a==1'm or other. How can I select rows based on the partial value of the MultiIndex? I am on pandas version `0.17.0`, and I'm unwilling to upgrade, as `0.18` is not supported by conda yet

---

#### Data Frame Creation

I'm starting with this dataframe

```
     a    c    k    y  T        S         t
0    5  0.4  0.2  0.9  1  1.98521   0.90772
1  0.1  0.4  0.2    1  1  49.9547  0.935831
2    5  0.4  0.2    1  1  2.00426  0.905521
3    5  0.4  0.2    1  5  0.54526   4.02065
4  0.1  0.4  0.2    1  5  16.4644   4.26893
```

And then I want to have it in a way such that I have `S` and `t` for different `y` on the same row:

```
df.set_index(['T', 'a', 'k', 'c', 'y'], inplace=True)
df = df.stack().unstack(4)

df2 = df.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
```

This is how it looks now (plus some additional columns)

#### Data Frame Creation Take 2

Alternatively, here is `df2.reset_index()`:

```
In [36]: df2.reset_index()
Out[36]: 
     T    a    k    c         S         t         S         t       s-diff  \
y                           0.9       0.9       1.0       1.0                
0    1  0.1  0.2  0.4       NaN       NaN   49.9547  0.935831          NaN   
1    1  0.1  0.2  0.5   48.4641   0.91747   51.6021  0.893594       -3.138   
2    1  0.1  0.3  0.4   43.3879  0.930355   44.7448  0.935127     -1.35695   
3    1  0.1  0.3  0.5   43.1652  0.915278   45.5227  0.888028     -2.35748   
4    1  1.0  0.2  0.4   7.82282  0.922999   7.95204   0.93587    -0.129213   
5    1  1.0  0.2  0.5   7.82921  0.910954   7.95381  0.908296    -0.124604   
6    1  1.0  0.3  0.4    7.3131  0.923834   7.41049  0.929179   -0.0973891   
7    1  1.0  0.3  0.5   7.31753  0.911348   7.45975  0.907871    -0.142221   
8    1  5.0  0.2  0.4   1.98521   0.90772   2.00426  0.905521   -0.0190501   
9    1  5.0  0.2  0.5   2.11855    0.9082   2.02325  0.891608    0.0953023   
10   1  5.0  0.3  0.4   1.87945  0.908802   1.90995  0.937631   -0.0305015   
11   1  5.0  0.3  0.5   1.88057   0.89712   1.91215  0.868879   -0.0315846   
12   5  0.1  0.2  0.4   16.4244   3.52755   16.4644   4.26893   -0.0400153   
13   5  0.1  0.3  0.4       NaN       NaN   16.0271   3.61533          NaN   
14   5  0.1  0.3  0.5   15.2237   3.80595       NaN       NaN          NaN   
15   5  1.0  0.2  0.4   2.35366   3.80512    2.3596   3.79693   -0.0059349   
16   5  1.0  0.2  0.5   2.34645    3.8176   2.51691   3.04467    -0.170462   
17   5  1.0  0.3  0.4   2.19598   3.78134   2.21581   3.74906    -0.019823   
18   5  1.0  0.3  0.5   2.34471   3.26898   2.34466   3.26885  4.97027e-05   
19   5  5.0  0.2  0.4  0.541352   3.79937   0.54526   4.02065  -0.00390801   
20   5  5.0  0.2  0.5  0.566614   3.87528  0.567599    3.8671 -0.000984482   
21   5  5.0  0.3  0.4  0.520307    4.2113   0.51744   3.71401   0.00286746   
22   5  5.0  0.3  0.5  0.554546   3.47341   0.55858   3.44815  -0.00403361   
23  10  0.1  0.3  0.5    9.3711   6.70258       NaN       NaN          NaN   
24  10  1.0  0.2  0.5   1.35114   6.84992   1.35207   6.84496 -0.000936299   

         t-diff       S-elas       t-elas  
y                                          
0           NaN          NaN          NaN  
1     0.0238751    -0.595826     0.250475  
2   -0.00477195    -0.292537   -0.0486025  
3     0.0272504    -0.505053     0.287115  
4    -0.0128704    -0.155631    -0.131551  
5    0.00265812    -0.150001     0.027761  
6   -0.00534445    -0.125675   -0.0547997  
7    0.00347693    -0.182862    0.0363132  
8    0.00219903   -0.0907268    0.0230424  
9     0.0165924     0.437187     0.175161  
10    -0.028829    -0.152934    -0.296654  
11    0.0282413    -0.158226     0.303842  
12    -0.741378   -0.0231171     -1.80674  
13          NaN          NaN          NaN  
14          NaN          NaN          NaN  
15   0.00818596   -0.0239247    0.0204594  
16     0.772931    -0.665956      2.14006  
17    0.0322827   -0.0853706    0.0814527  
18  0.000129179  0.000201381  0.000375417  
19     -0.22128   -0.0683336    -0.537635  
20    0.0081767   -0.0164918    0.0200658  
21     0.497293       0.0525       1.1922  
22    0.0252581   -0.0688499    0.0693348  
23          NaN          NaN          NaN  
24    0.0049623  -0.00658096    0.0068846
```

Call this dataframe `test`. Then `test.set_index(['T', 'a', 'k', 'c'], inplace=True).query('a == 1')` gives me the same error as above.

Comment: I think your error has to do with the formatting of your dataframe.  Can you post an example of how you created your dataframe so that someone else can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hm.  That works fine for me - no error.  Is it possible you have an older version of Pandas? Do you get the same error for your sample dataframe (that you just added)?

Comment: @CharlieHaley: It's even weirder: When I do this on the dataframe I posted (using `pd.read_clipboard()`), I get an error when I'm trying to `unstack(4)`: `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater`

Comment: When I do this on the data frame I posted (using `df.head()` instead of `pd.read_clipboard()`), I get the same error as in the question on the full data-frame.

Comment: @CharlieHaley I've added a second way of creating the data (instead of starting with the initial one)

Comment: Still works fine for me. No error here.